# Matrix multiplication quickly overflows in backpropagation equations

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

I'm trying to do my own neural network implementation from scratch, but I'm having some problems. Specifically, with the way one of the terms grows exponentially as iterations advance, which makes the accuracy quickly reach a plateau and gradient descent not find any optimal solution.

The equations I'm using I reached on my own, while studying some of the available resources online. I chose to write my own equations so I could understand them better:

[image: delta of last layer] ... (1) where L is the last layer, and the hadamard product is being performed, and A is the values from the Lth layer after the activation function, Z is the values before the activation function is applied.

[image]... (2) where W is the matrix of weights from the i+1th layer, with the number of rows is equal to the number of neurons in the i+1th layer and columns equals the number of neurones in the ith layer.

[image]... (3)

[image]... (4)

I struggled a lot with these, but I finally was able to make it work and keep all the correct dimensions of each matrix. Now, implementing these equations into my code:

```
def back_prop(self):
    delta = np.multiply(self.a_record[-1] - self.target, self.layers[-1].prime(self.z_record[-1]))

    for i, layer in reversed(list(enumerate(self.layers))):
        dw = np.matmul(delta, self.a_record[i].T)
        db = np.matmul(delta, np.ones((self.n, 1)))

        self.dw_record.append(dw)
        self.db_record.append(db)
        
        if i > 0:
            delta = np.multiply(np.matmul(self.w[i].T, delta), layer.prime(self.z_record[i - 1]))
```

a_record and z_record are lists that store the arrays corresponding to each layer. Same for dw and db records. I wrote it like this so it is as close as possible to my equations.
Problem comes once I start to measure performance on any dataset, which remain stagnant after just a couple of iterations. I get this warning, since it's not an error it doesn't stop the script.

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply delta = np.multiply(self.a_record[-1] - self.target, self.layers[-1].prime(self.z_record[-1]))
```

When I analize the values that come from delta I find that the value of delta is growing way too fast, it starts with small values but grows up to e+200 magnitude and then it just returns infinity, which makes the next delta a bunch of np.nan and all the weights and biases to stop changing.
I'm fairly certain that the equations are equivalent to other equations I found in other neural networks, so I don't really know why this is happening. I don't imagine the values from any randomly generated dataset to be so insanely big that it overflows after just a couple of iterations.
I will post the whole class I made:

```
class Network():
def __init__(self, input, target, layers, alpha = 0.1, iter= 1000):
    self.input = np.array(input).T
    self.y_true = target
    #self.target = np.array(one_hot(target)).T
    self.target = np.array(target).T
    self.layers = layers
    self.alpha = alpha
    self.iter = iter
    self.n = len(input)

    self.w = []
    self.b = []

    for i, layer in enumerate(layers):
        if i == 0:
            self.w.append(np.random.rand(layer.neurons, len(self.input)) - 0.5)
        else:
            self.w.append(np.random.rand(layer.neurons, layers[i - 1].neurons) - 0.5)

        self.b.append(np.random.rand(layer.neurons, 1) - 0.5)


    self.a_record = []
    self.z_record = []

    self.dw_record = []
    self.db_record = []


def forward_prop(self):
    a = self.input
    self.a_record.append(a)

    for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):

        z = np.matmul(self.w[i], a) + self.b[i].reshape(-1, 1)
        a = layer.func(z)

        self.z_record.append(z)
        self.a_record.append(a)
    
    self.output = a


def back_prop(self):
    delta = np.multiply(self.a_record[-1] - self.target, self.layers[-1].prime(self.z_record[-1]))

    print(delta)
    for i, layer in reversed(list(enumerate(self.layers))):
        dw = np.matmul(delta, self.a_record[i].T)
        db = np.matmul(delta, np.ones((self.n, 1)))

        self.dw_record.append(dw)
        self.db_record.append(db)
        
        print(self.a_record[i].T)
        print("------------------------------------------")

        if i > 0:
            delta = np.multiply(np.matmul(self.w[i].T, delta), layer.prime(self.z_record[i - 1]))


def gradient_desc(self):
    w_copy = self.w
    for i, (w, dw) in enumerate(zip(w_copy, self.dw_record[::-1])):
        self.w[i] = w - self.alpha*dw

    b_copy = self.b
    for i, (b, db) in enumerate(zip(b_copy, self.db_record[::-1])):
        self.b[i] = b - self.alpha*db


def fit(self):
    for i in range(self.iter):
        self.forward_prop()
        self.back_prop()
        self.gradient_desc()

        if i % 40 == 0:
            print(f"Iteration: {i + 1} / {self.iter} =====================================")
            print(f"Accuracy: {get_accuracy(self.output, self.y_true)}")
```

I've been trying for a couple days now to figure this out, but I don't seem to find the error or maybe a workaround to prevent overflow. Maybe the equations are wrong from the start? Please any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.